# Auto assign value-message to rows in a table with MySQL trigger

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Im testing a trigger for an assignment where i need to set an specific value to each row on a table.

I have  2 tables tbl_cursos and tbl_modalidad. After i insert an entry on tbl_cursos the trigger must  take 1 value from that table and add it to tbl_modalidad. Also the trigger must insert on tbl_modalidad a specifica value to Tipo_modalidad column, the value is "Presencial", then insert the date.

This is what i have

```
CREATE TRIGGER bienvenida 
AFTER INSERT 
ON tbl_cursos FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
INSERT INTO tbl_modalidad (id_modalidad, tipo_modalidad, fecha_registro) 
VALUES (new.id_modalidad, `Presencial`, now());
```

After running the trigger i got an error message with  `Presencial`. I've tried to use SET table = 'message' but is wrong. Everything works perfectly if i delete the "presencial" value.

Comment: It looks as if you are using backticks as a string delimiter. Try: 'Presencial' instead. Backticks is MySQL way of quoting identifiers (the standard way is double quotes). Never quote values (and avoid quoting in all other places).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL backticks are used for table and column identifiers and are necessary when the identifier is a [MySQL reserved keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html) or when the identifier contains whitespace characters, even though  it is recommended to avoid using reserved keywords as column/table names or column/table names with spaces.

If the ANSI_QUOTES SQL mode is enabled, string literals can be quoted only within single quotation marks because a string quoted within double quotation marks is interpreted as an identifier https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-literals.html.

In your case Presencial should be single quoted, full trigger should be as below:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER bienvenida  AFTER INSERT  ON tbl_cursos 
  FOR EACH ROW 
       BEGIN
       INSERT INTO tbl_modalidad (id_modalidad, tipo_modalidad, fecha_registro) 
       VALUES (new.id_modalidad, 'Presencial', NOW());

    END//
DELIMITER ;
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6LMbhugzVigtcxJzVkCVLs/1

You will find better explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql) that will hekp you understand the use case of quotes